# Qlikview Load Script - Appending a field and applying a value where no match exists

Tags: qlikview

I'm trying to join two tables, **hlo2aLookup** and **ODP_StudySite** in my load script. Here's the load script:

```
hlo2aNewCol:
LOAD [~SiteKey]
RESIDENT hlo2aLookup;

left Join 
LOAD [~SiteKey],[~SiteKey] as [Key2],
if(exists([~SiteKey],[~SiteKey]),'y','n') as [Key2Exits],
if(isnull([~SiteKey]),'y','n') as [Key2isNull]

Resident ODP_StudySite;
```

The matchkey is **~Sitekey**, and where there is no match on table, i want it to display 'No match', instead of a null value. I have tested EXISTS and ISNULL (as seen in example below, in **Key2Exists** and **Key2IsNull**) - However it isn't working. This is what i'm seeing in the table right now:

[image: Table Example]

Any ideas?

Best wishes

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont think you can "flag" the records before/during the tables are joined.
You can achieve this in few steps:

1. join the tables into a temp table (in the script below `hlo2aNewCol_Temp`)
2. use the result from the temp table and write your logic here. This table will be the "final" one
3. drop the temp table

```
hlo2aNewCol_Temp:
LOAD 
  [~SiteKey]
RESIDENT hlo2aLookup;

left Join 

LOAD 
  [~SiteKey],
  [~SiteKey] as [Key2]
Resident ODP_StudySite;

hlo2aNewCol:
Load
  [~SiteKey],
  Key2,     // this is probably not needed. just for reference.
  if( isNull(Key2), 'No Match', Key2 ) as KeyStatus
Resident hlo2aNewCol_Temp;

Drop Table hlo2aNewCol_Temp;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much.